# javascript: native xml api

Tags: javascript

does javascript has native xml api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla implementations of JavaScript (Rhino and Spidermonkey) includes an extension to the standard JavaScript syntax that adds a native syntax for XML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/e4x

This can allow declarative creation of XML literals (which can span multiple lines - a nice workaround for js's lack of support for multi-line strings), as well as a syntax for XPath-like querying.

Answer (score 1):

No. XML and DOM functionality are provided by the browser. Use something like [XML for <SCRIPT>](http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/) if you need it independent of a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected, but i think most of JavaScript's DOM api can be used to access an XML document.

Comment: It can, but it isn't a native api.